Trying to hide a batch file from Nirsoft SoundVolumeCommandLine
The problem I'm facing is that some commands don't work, that's what I'm doing
I'm using:
svcl.exe /SetDefault High-Speakers 1 or all

what I done was creating a VBS file with:
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False

then calling it as shortcut:
wscript.exe "C:\Wherever\invisible.vbs" "C:\Some Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat"

window start invisible, but svcl.exe does not work

You might find this to be easier: RunHidden

clarify: does your command line actually contain 1 or all? I note all their their examples enclose the device name in quotes

svcl.exe is an independent program, which means it does not require to be hosted by a batch file. Just create a shortcut to run svcl or if you really must, a vbs running svcl. There is absolutely no reason to involve a batch file in this process.

@Compo This is a program that serves as a command line, it always opens a batch file even if I go to the direct .exe

@Yorik I Currently use 1, I don't know the real difference between these two commands, they both work for what I trying to do

@joth, it is just a command line utility. Are you sure it doesn't just run in the default command line interface, by the sounds of it, cmd.exe.

@Compo the .exe program executes a cmd even without the batch when I write the command directly in its path
I tried using this command:
| CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False |
written in a VBS and calling it before the svcl, it is invisible but the svcl command does not proceed. this is the problem I am facing
(yes the command works, I tried opening some applications with it)

@LesFerch This works well, but what I really wanted was something like a VBS so I could use it on any Windows

@joth, that's exactly the point I was making. You do not need a batch file, the executable itself runs in cmd.exe, let's call that a 'shell', (although technically it isn't). At the very most you, yourself, would run cmd.exe with the options /d and /c followed by the quoted argument string "svcl.exe /SetDefault High-Speakers 1", and the current working directory for your vbscript or even the shortcut, as the parent directory of svcl.exe.

I should also say that the help information for that utility is readily available, so you should be aware that 0 is Console, 1 is Multimedia, 2 is Communications and you should have guessed by now, all sets Console, Multimedia, and Communications. I should also mention that if you intend to run this on "any Windows", you'd need to know not only the location of the end users svcl.exe file, but be certain that they have also the name High- Speakers.

According to my comments, here are a couple of examples of what the VBScript may look like, without any need to introduce a batch file into your process. The idea is to handle the cmd.exe host process your utility currently spawns, so that we control its visibility.
This one defines the parent directory of the third party utility as the current directory, (you'll have to change yours as needed):
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Users\joth\CLI-Tools\svcl-x64"
objShell.Run "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C " & Chr(34) & "svcl.exe /SetDefault High-Speakers 1" & Chr(34) & "", 0, False

This one expects the current directory to be the parent directory of the same utility, but you run this one as a shortcut, and input, (your equivalent of), C:\Users\joth\CLI-Tools\svcl-x64 into the 'Start in:' box within the Shortcut Properties dialog window.
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C " & Chr(34) & "svcl.exe /SetDefault High-Speakers 1" & Chr(34) & "", 0, False

Please also take note of the other comments I made regarding problems you may encounter, should you be intending to run this on "any Windows".
